# Trouble installing SciPy on windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, scipy

I have Python 2.7 and NumPy installed.  I have downloaded pre-built binaries for SciPy, but the install script fails with this error:

Blas `(http://www.netlib.org/blas/)` libraries not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
`numpy/distutils/site.cfg` file (section `[blas]`) or by setting
the BLAS environment variable.

I really don't know enough about this to fool with it.  I assumed it was a straightforward install process, but doesn't appear to be.  I googled for the BLAS environment variable, but couldn't find anything that seemed appropriate.  Any help is appreciated.

Mike

EDIT: Nevermind, I found an unofficial [installer exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.11.0/).

Comment: The exe you metion seems official package on sourceforge.

Comment: If you don't want more pain, try Anaconda(https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_windows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To install SciPy on Windows you have to have a fortran compiler installed.  The SciPy project recommends MinGW.  See [Building and installing SciPy](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Installing_SciPy/Windows).  To install MinGW follow these instructions: [HOWTO Install the MinGW (GCC) Compiler Suite](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW).  Then before you run pip or easy_install to install SciPy make sure that you have MinGW added to your path.  See [MinGW Installation Notes - Environmental Variables](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started#toc4)

A side note, It would be easier to use either the [Enthought Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) (part of the initial install) or the [Active State Distribution](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) ([through pypm 32-bit only](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/scipy/)) as they already have precomiled binary packages for SciPy.  Or, you could use the SciPy precompiled binary [package installer for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.16.1).

Comment: The Fortran compiler is only used for the source code, not the pre-built binaries, right?  Because it's the pre-built binaries that are the problem.  I'll try the package installer you mentioned, I think the one I was using was different.

Comment: I use EPD.  EPD has it built into the basic installation already.  On Mac and Linux, every install of SciPy I have done has required gcc and gfortran.  The install notes say it is a prerequisite on Windows.  See -> http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/browser/trunk/INSTALL.txt?rev=4543

Comment: I ran the package installer and all seems to be good now.  Thanks.  Fortran not required.

Comment: This method did not work for me right out of the box.  The installer says I need to have Python 2.7 installed (which I do have installed) - saying it can't find it in the registry (I did *not* install Python2.7 with an msi, so no surprise here really).

Answer (score 14):

Try installing using Scipy wheel file. Download it from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Make sure to download the one that's compatible with your Python version and your laptop bit. Then install it like this: `pip install "path\to\your\wheel\file\scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl"`

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks! CP35 was my version of Python, I was trying with 36, inadvertently, I didn't realise this was the python version - Thanks!

Comment: this really helped me to get an idea on how to solve my problem .In my case  i have python 3.6 so pip install scipy didn't work i had to download the .whl file and then did pip install "C:\Users\folder\Downloads\scipy-0.19.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl"

Answer (score 1):

Here I am going to share what I have done to install **scipy**.

> MY PC Configuration is `windows-7 64-bit & python 2.7`

- **First**  I download  the required packages form  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (which version match your configuration EX: cp27==>python2.7 & cp36==>3.6)
- **Second**  I extract the file using `7zip` (also can be used any zipper like winrar)
- **Third** I copy the `scipy` folder which I extracted and paste it into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` (or put it where the exact location is in your PC like `..\..\Lib\site-packages`)

> NOTE: Have to install **numpy** `first` before installing **scipy** in this same way.

Comment: Do you then have to run pip install pointing to the packages you pasted into the site-packages folder? e.g. pip install c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy (I am reinstalling NumPy from the site because it said it was linked against the MKL (intel math kernel or something like that).

Comment: Nevermind - I learned how to install a .whl using pip like this, which worked well for me: pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/where/its/downloaded package_name  This info from stack overflow post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file

Comment: @condiosluzverde There is no need to run pip install pointing to the folder if you follow the above instruction and it has worked for me. Which .whl file we are going to install we have to first download the actual file than we may install using pip or the above process. Thank you so much your comments also clearing my answer. And I have also learned to install a .whl file using pip.

Answer (score 0):

To install Scipy on Windows requires a C compiler and the presence of 3rd party C libraries on the system which are difficult to install on Windows. However you can use a Wheel (.whl) file through your command prompt to install Scipy.

I faced the same problem and this is what I did:

Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy and download the version of Scipy which is compatible with your system and the Python version you have installed
e.g If you have 32-Bit Windows and Python 3.6 installed then you download the version with cp36 (version3.6) and Win-32.

After downloading copy this file in the directory where you have installed Python either in the Scripts or Lib folder.

Next use the command prompt to install it after changing to the directory where you have copied the file:

```
C:\....> pip install scipy-1.0.0b1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
```

Answer (score -2):

Steps to download scipy on Windows-

```
1.Go to website sourceforge.net

2.Click Files

3.Downlaod the type you want

4.Install it.
```

Very easy and it worked for me.