# Regarding installing SciPy from PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, pycharm

I have been trying to install SciPy in PyCharm on Windows 7. But the installation process failed with the following error message.

[image]

Then I followed the steps listed in [install Python package with .whl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file/27909082#27909082),

```
pip install wheel
pip install some-package.whl
```

The installation process was successful. However, I still cannot find the SciPy package from `PyCharm`.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the [Numpy wheel which is linked against the Intel Math Kernel](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)? After you do this you should be able to install SciPy with pip (which is what PyCharm uses) since your error is with Numpy and not SciPy.

Comment: But I installed NumPy from PyCharm using its own installation process successfully. The second figure in the above show that NumPy was listed as well. I also tested some code using NumPy. It works fine, why it still causes problem when installing SciPy.

Comment: I'm still guessing you are missing a Fortran compiler and blas/lapack libraries. Numpy will work without them, allthough slower sometimes. Some SciPy functions require them - hence why I linked a prebuilt Numpy binary with them included. You could also try [building SciPy with the correct compilers from source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628164/trouble-installing-scipy-on-windows).

Answer (score 2):

If you've gotten over the NumPy/wheel issues in installing SciPy on Windows 7, then this is a relatively quick fix. In short, you need to add the path where SciPy lives (only a few subfolders away from Python). You can see a general summary of adding paths in PyCharm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm).

Open a Python Interpreter where you can open SciPy.

```
>> import scipy
>> scipy.__file__
"path/to/scipy"
```

Here is what my path looked like:

```
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy
```

So, SciPy is installed in Continuum, whereas Python lives in its own directory. The default interpreter paths in PyCharm look in the Python directory, shown below:

```
file://C:/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/DLLs
file://C:/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib
file://C:/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35
file://C:/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages
file://C:/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/win32
file://C:/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/win32/lib
file://C:/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/pythonwin
```

To fix this, open PyCharm and head to menu *File* → *Settings* → *Project Interpreter*. Open the ProjectInterprets, and there is a small button on the right side labelled "show paths". I added my path up to SciPy:

```
file://C:/Users/ME/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/
```

Go ahead and add your path here, and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with installing SciPy in Pycharm and I solved it by downloading scipy as an exe file for my python version from sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/

Now I can see scipy in my project interpreter and use it without errors.

Comment: What do you do after downloading the exe file ? There is no exe file from the link. There is only compressed file from the link, and then what do you do with it ? Thanks

Comment: this required python 3.4. I installed 3.4 but the setup couldn't find where is it.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate you need blas/lapack, which are numerical libraries that scipy uses. They're not Python packages, you'll have to install them yourself. There are several implementations, some of which combine blas and lapack so you only need to install one.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to install the package "Anaconda". SciPy will automatically be installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody searching this.

Download:

Numpy + MKL from:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
Make sure you select your version of python 
(mine is 3.6, hence I use: obspy‑1.0.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl)

Then download Scipy from:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
(again 3.6 is: scipy‑1.0.0b1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl)

open up your folder containing pip in command prompt as admin:

pip install C:/user/Daniel/obspy‑1.0.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

pip install C:/user/Daniel/scipy‑1.0.0b1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whlhl

The PyCharm should automatically find it.

Apologies posting on a dead-thread.