# How do I install a .whl file in a PyCharm virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

The package manager in Project Interpreter doesn't appear to have any way for me to run a pure pip command so I'm unable to install the wheel as I normally would through command line.

Running through command line installs the wheel on my base python install and not the virtualenv. Help?

Comment: Have you tried using the [PyCharm GUI for installing packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)?

Comment: Related (but doesn't seem to be delicate, and has no accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663601/regarding-install-scipy-from-pycharm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install via your command line, and avoid installing on your *base* Python, you'll have to first **activate** the `virtualenv`.

You can do this on POSIX using:

```
$ source path_to_your_venv/bin/activate
```

And then for Windows systems:

```
> path_to_venv\Scripts\activate
```

You can then install the [`.whl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) file with `pip install filename.whl` while the virtual env has been activated.

Comment: Thanks Moses, this did the trick.
For Pycharm venv's the path is 'path_to_venv/Scripts/activate.bat

Comment: @Awebb I didn't remember it was windows. I updated :)

Comment: I'm able to install the wheel from local dir but couldn't install it from PyCharm, why is that?

Answer (score 15):

You can install it from PyCharm's Python console with the pip module :

```
import pip

def install_whl(path):
    pip.main(['install', path])

install_whl("path/to/file.whl")
```

Comment: Inspired from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code

Comment: pip.main() only available before 10.0.0 version

Answer (score 3):

My environment is Windows 7 and Python 2.7.12.

Steps to install whl packages into venv:

1. Search package on [Python Extension Packages for Windows - Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
2. Download package, for example, `mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl` to `C:\Root\python\whls\mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl`
3. Open PyCharm Python Console and execute script below:

```py
import pip
from pip._internal import main as pipmain


def install_whl(path):
    pipmain(['install', path])


install_whl('C:\Root\python\whls\mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl')
```

Answer (score 0):

The whl file (opencv package) is in c:\SmartSight\OPCV:

```
c:\SmartSight\OPCV>pip install opencv_python-3.4.3+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\smartsight\opcv\opencv_python-3.4.3+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-3.4.3+contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of pip._internal in PyCharm Python Console generates WARNING message

see:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7498

> Move the current entrypoint from pip._internal.main:main to pip._internal.cli.main:main

in PyCharm Python Console use:

```
import pip
from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pipmain
pipmain(['install', path&packagename])
```