# Cannot install xgboost library on python virtual enviroment

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, xgboost

I am using `PyCharm` and `Python 3.6` for 32-bit `Windows`.

I try to install the `xgboost` library for python by going on `Pycharm` to `File` -> `Default Settings` and choosing a virtual ennviroment interpreter used by all my projects (`C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project_name\venv\Scripts\python.exe`) instead of the local(`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe`).

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Collecting xgboost
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/3a/8570f4e8e19acd3a5a75abc920964182a4b64db2ee0f041fb77b48447c6b/xgboost-0.72.tar.gz

No files/directories in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\xgboost\pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

I am getting the same exactly error when I enter at the command prompt window

```
C:\Users\User>PycharmProjects\Sentdex_ML\venv\Scripts\pip install xgboost
```

I have also read a relevant StackOverflow post ([How to install xgboost package in python (windows platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform/35119904#35119904)) and followed the (most upvoted) answer of @brettlyman.

Specifically, I donwloaded `xgboost-0.72-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` and I entered at the command prompt

```
pip install xgboost-0.72-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
```

However, in this way I successfuly installed `xgboost` on my local interpreter and not on my virtual enviroment interpreter which I am actually using. (Therefore @Moses' answer regarding Windows was not useful either - [How do I install a .whl file in a PyCharm virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791243/how-do-i-install-a-whl-file-in-a-pycharm-virtualenv))

**How can I install `xgboost` on my virtual enviroment?**

When I enter `pip3 install xgboost` at the `command promt window` then I am getting the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from xgboost)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from xgboost)
```

Therefore, by entering this it is again verified that `xgboost` is installed at my local interpreter (but not on my virtual enviroment).

Comment: Have you tried using `pip`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I answered your question at the end of my post. What do you think?

Comment: I think you haven't properly linked Pycharm to the right python. Your question is about linking Pycharm to Python, not installing xgboost.

Comment: Haha, ok. This is pretty obvious. The question is what do I have to do to do it properly. Also, keep in mind please that I was capable of installing directly from the Pycharm Project Interpreter window many other ibraries (sk-learn, keras etc) on my virtual enviroment so it has also something to do with `xgboost`.

Comment: I would start a new one about linking Pycharm and pip to the same thing, Just my two cents.

Comment: @Poete_Maudit You are supposed to **activate** the virtual environment, and then use pip. Not just try to run pip from the virtual env directory like you've done. The answer I gave clearly states this.

Comment: Oh, apologies for this @Moses. Yes, you certainly write this at your post but it was not so clear to me when I was reading this. Consider to re-edit your post a little bit but in general your answer is absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: @Poete_Maudit Ok, answer updated.

Comment: That's great! (To be honest the phrase at your post "And then for Windows systems:" was also quite confusing. If I am right you really mean 'or for Windows systems:" since at least in my case I am not doing anything with any POSIX and I think that the question itself at this post does not mention it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to do this and finally `xgboost` is properly installed on my virtual enviroment.

Specifically I did the following:

1. I downloaded xgboost `.whl` file from this [url](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
2. I opened the `command prompt` (`cmd`)
3. I activated the specific virtual enviroment by entering `C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project_name\venv\Scripts\activate` at the `cmd`
4. then I entered/went at the `cmd` to the folder directory where the `.whl` file is stored
5. finally I entered `pip install xgboost-0.72-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` in this directory at the `cmd`

Thanks to @brettyman and @Moses because a combination of their answers at [How to install xgboost package in python (windows platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform/35119904#35119904) and at [How do I install a .whl file in a PyCharm virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791243/how-do-i-install-a-whl-file-in-a-pycharm-virtualenv) respectively solved my problem.