# Is it possible to use an Anaconda Python 3 environment together with Pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pycharm, anaconda

My basic problem is that I want to install scipy on a Window's machine for Python 3 and use Pycharm as my development environment.

The suggestion from the [Scipy Documentation](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) as well as several StackOverflow posts ([Installing NumPy and SciPy on 64-bit Windows (with Pip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657334/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-64-bit-windows-with-pip), [Trouble installing SciPy on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628164/trouble-installing-scipy-on-windows), etc.) is to use Anaconda to install a prebuilt scipy and avoid the Fortran and C compilers.

I've used Anaconda for Python 2.7 in the past, so I created an Anaconda environment for Python 3 following [these directions](http://continuum.io/blog/anaconda-python-3).

Command to create the environment

```
conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda
```

And the command to activate the environment

```
source activate py3k
```

This works fine, but I do most of my development in PyCharm and I can't figure out how to activate the Anaconda environment from PyCharm. Is there a way to do this or should I take another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanations how to configure PyCharm with Anaconda can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration.html).

In PyCharm preferences you can just select the correct python interpreter under,

> Project Interpreter > Python Interpreters

As pointed out by @Cecilia, in the case when a virtual environment (e.g. named `py3k`) is used with Anaconda, the correct python interpreter is located under,

```
~/Anaconda/envs/py3k/python.exe
```

Comment: I would add that the Anaconda environments are located in the 'envs' directory. So the correct interpreter for my example environment, is located at '~/Anaconda/envs/py3k/python.exe'. That was the piece that I was missing when I asked the question, if you add it to your answer, I will accept it.