# Error installing sklearn from pip (Python3) in Windows

Tags: python, windows, scikit-learn, pip

When I try to install sklearn from pip using pip install -U scikit-learn, I get this error, I already installed numpy

trying to install scipy also gives some error.

[image: Error while installing scikit-learn]

[image: Error while installing scipy]

Comment: The error is because the scipy package (a dependency of scikit) is not installed. Simply use `pip install scikit-learn`. It should install all dependencies first. If still not installed, first use `pip install scipy` and then `pip install scikit-learn`. In case of windows, sometimes pip dont work correctly, then search this here on SO, it has already many answers available about using the `whl` file for installing.

Comment: And you said "installing scipy gives the same error". Can you share what exact error its giving?

Comment: Error when trying to install scipy: http://imgur.com/a/5s9Fv

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628164/trouble-installing-scipy-on-windows/42664324#42664324) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) .