# error in installing scipy in windows

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

when i ran $pip install scipy , i got this error

```
C:\Users\setCodesToFire>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\setcod~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-xhdrq1\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\setcod~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-fau9k8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
  pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\setcod~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-xhdrq1\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "c:\users\setcod~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-xhdrq1\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "c:\users\setcod~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-xhdrq1\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\setcod~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-xhdrq1\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\setcod~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-fau9k8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\setcod~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-xhdrq1\scipy\

can anybody help me out in this? I dont know how to make this right

Comment: Read the official docs and any of those 100 other questions asking exactly the same here. Short story: ```pip install scipy``` is not gonna work on windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble installing SciPy on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628164/trouble-installing-scipy-on-windows)